# How do I account for different sample sizes when combining this data in a density plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, normalize, density-plot

I'm using R and ggplot to generate density plots that compare soil type and a plant leaf trait. The goal is to have 3 'humps' so three data sets each corresponding to different soil. But two of the soil types (N and S) have measurements from multiple regions, each with varying numbers of entries. For example, I have about 600 values from California but only 20 from Lesbos for the N and S data sets.

Below I attached a sample graph. So each one of the humps represents a soil type but I'm afraid the S and N soil types are skewed by having the majority of their values from California.

[Sample Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgmA6.png)

I don't want the California data to skew the density for those 'humps' simply because I have more data. Is there a way, other than randomly selecting 20 values from each location, that I can give the locations equal weight?
Thanks.

I'm just using the simple ggplot command:

```
ggplot(data=combined_sla) + 
  geom_density(aes(x = SLA, fill = Data), alpha=0.4)+
  theme_classic()+ 
  labs(x = "SLA (mm2 mg-1)", y = "Density")+
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete=TRUE, option="magma")
```

Comment: please include code and example

Comment: Please see updated post.